# Как сверстать элемент?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте)
Не могу сверстать элемент (на рисунке) , правая часть имеет ширину "по содержимому" + некоторый padding, а левая часть растягивается на всю доступную ширину.

Пробовал делать через table и через div, но никак не могу.
PS. Линию делаю как border у нижних элементов, в одном из таких элементов написано "by admin ...."
[image]

Comment: хм) я вот щас подумал, а возможно эту линию просто картинку вставлять, т.е вне зависимости от нижней надписи. Просто верстаю (в первый раз) с psd-шаблона и не всегда понятно что и как должно быть)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например [можно так](http://jsfiddle.net/8X2zk/)

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    тут заголовочный текст выаываыфва ыфваыф
</div>
<div style="display: table; width: 100%">
    <div style="display: table-row"> 
        <div class="c1"></div>
        <div class="c2">
            by admin. yes or no?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.c1 {
    display: table-cell;
    border-top: 2px gray solid;
    width: 100%;
}
.c2 {
    display: table-cell;
    border-top: 2px orange solid;
    white-space: nowrap;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы жуть как усложняете, какие таблицы? Попробуйте вот так: http://jsfiddle.net/AJdrr/1/

Код HTML:

```
<div class="item">
   <h1>There is no knowelge...</h1>
   <h2>That he has power</h2>
</div>
```

Код CSS:

```
.item { text-align: right; }
.item h1 { text-align: left; border-bottom: 2px solid #444; }
.item h2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: -2px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

а какие тут могут быть проблемы? Правой части float:right, а левой overflow: hidden. Естественно, правая часть должна первой в коде идти